# Value of "of course" in the mathematical literature

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, mathematical-writing

I've been thinking about the value of writing "of course" in mathematical papers (or its variants such as "obviously" etc.).  In particular, my current train of thought is, if something is obvious, then it is obvious that it is obvious (so why include it at all?).

The example that inspired this post is:  If d divides a and d divides b, then *of course* d also divides a+b.

> Are there examples in the mathematical literature where the term "of course" is of value?

More precisely, I'm after an example (or a few), ideally by a well-known author, where "of course" or "obviously" or similar actually adds tangible value to a sentence (rather than just implying: (a) it's obvious to me, I'm so smart or (b) I can't actually be bothered working out the details)

Comment: It is of value, I think, to separate the routine parts of an argument from the nontrivial parts.  But, _of course_, what is routine depends heavily on one's background.

Comment: When I read papers I usually pause a bit at the "obviously", "trivially" and "of course" just to make sure I've followed everything.  I think the value of these phrases isn't necessarily one in terms of manipulating pieces of a logical argument, but rather a style choice to break up the flow and give readers with less background or experience a chance to think things through with something easy.

Comment: I'll just note: reading this post lead me to search the paper I'm in the process of revising for "Obviously" and "Of course."  I didn't delete all of them though; I kept, for example, "Obviously, this is a dissatisfying state of affairs..." refering to a theorem I hadn't proved.

Comment: These keywords should be red flags when you're writing: you'll want to thoroughly check any of those statements. But they have their place, especially in the more expository parts of a paper, to distinguish facts that are easily proved -- an invitation to the readers to prove it for themselves -- from facts that are not easy at all, but happen to be well known (or ought to be well-known).

Comment: Also asked at [Mathematics StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/474698/18398) and [Academia StackExchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10797/64).

Comment: I would say that it often means 'it is obvious a posteriori". And this few words make the difference between men and machines. Machines don't say "of course", they say the obvious :-)

Comment: It's very useful when you are outlining your train of thought that led to a novel derivation.

Answer (score 82):

I don't agree that if something is obvious, then it is obvious that it is obvious. When an author declares in a mathematical exposition that a fact is obvious, or says "of course" or something with a similar meaning, then it is a  signal that the reader should be able to find a very easy reason justifying the statement, rather than a complex one. This is useful information for the author to signal, and I for one as a reader have often been grateful for it.

The truly aggravating uses of these phrases occur when the author says that something is "obvious" or "clear", but it isn't really. Surely many of us have been in situations reading a paper where the author says "clearly", but after a lot of thought, it still isn't so clear. I believe that these phrases are often used because the author didn't want to work out all the details, a kind of laziness, which can also be a dangerous source of mathematical error.

I have seen papers where the author states, "It is obvious that X, and let me explain why..."

Comment: Yes, when they claim a statement is obvious and it's not (not to some readers anyway), it's quite infuriating!  (especially when they're just big-noting themselves)

Comment: By the way, if it's not obviously obvious when you use "obvious", then perhaps the reader could interpret the use of "obvious" as one of those infuriating uses.  Eg. X is obvious if you think Y, but maybe the reader is trying to get Z to work, thinking "this is not obvious at all!".

Comment: I agree that was is obvious is not obvious. Sometimes you can lead yourself down a garden path by getting the idea that some statement is much more deep or complex than it really is. When someone points out that it is obvious, it helps me avoid such errors.

However, if I write something mathematical, I always sweep through it at least once looking for phrases like "of course", just to make sure they really are obvious. Somehow those phrases come to the fingers a little too easily.

Comment: Well, I think there is an entire scale of obviousness, depending on the reader and his or her background. If the author intends to write for a certain audience, presuming a certain background, then certain statements would be obvious, which might not be so clear to readers not in that intended audience. So when one reads that something is obvious, but it doesn't seem so clear, then it needn't necessarily reflect poorly on the author, but rather simply be an indicator that the reader was not in the intended audience.

Comment: Of course (!) it's the cases in which something is not only not obvious, but where it is not obvious that it's not obvious, that will bite you. (Sorry, I just couldn't resist this little Cheney moment.)

Comment: Harald, in this case, it is considered good writing style to say "Unclearly, ..."   :-)

Comment: Or “Unobviously, …” perhaps.

Comment: Harald, I believe that you were indulging in a Rumsfeld, not Cheney, moment:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknown_unknown#Usage.

Comment: Oh, rats! Rumsfeld it is. I should have looked it up. Oh well.

Comment: I think that Rumsfeld is vastly underrated ... as a mathematician.  I use that quote in my teaching a lot!

Comment: Not only are there statements that are obvious but not obviously obvious, I think there are cases where it's not so obvious that it's not obvious the statement is obvious.

Comment: I propose to introduce the modality $\square\varphi$ to mean `$\phi$ is obvious,' with the dual operator $\diamond\varphi$, which means `$\varphi$ is plausible,' with the equivalence $\diamond\varphi\iff\neg\square\neg\varphi$. In this language, JSE's assertions are those with $\neg\square\neg\square\square\varphi$, which can be dually expressed $\diamond\square\square\varphi$. 

Answer (score 50):

When I was a graduate student, a professor (who will remain nameless since I might be misquoting) said something along the lines of "If you want to see where the errors in a math paper are, just look for the places where the author states 'it is obvious that', 'clearly', or 'of course'."

Comment: This also holds for grading proofs on exams.  And it makes sense: if you the student don't know how to do a step in the proof, you might as well hope it's obvious to the grader!

Comment: That's a brilliant tactic!

Comment: "By a theorem of Euler..."

Comment: I have often found a mistake at exactly the "it is obvious that" places. There could be (at least) two reasons for this: 1) the author mistakenly believes something that is false, while thinking it is clearly true (this happens more often than we'd like to have); 2) the author has tried very hard to clearly spell out a proof of this step, which looks so obvious, but has given up (which is somewhat dishonest, because then it's obviously not obvious). 

Comment: Was it by any chance me? Probably not, but it is something I have often said. But I didn't think it up for myself -- I got it from David Preiss. It's useful not just for evaluating the work of others, but also one's own work. That is, if you've just written a proof of something but don't feel quite secure about it, look for the bits where you didn't give full detail.

Comment: Nope - not from you or Preiss.  But perhaps there is a common ancestor?

And I agree with the comments, that this applies not only to math papers, but to student work and my own!

Comment: I got something like that from most of my profs at some point...and I warn my students that if they use "of course", "trivial" or "obvious" in their homework, they lose points unless it REALLY is, like addition...in which case I mark on their paper that they don't need to point it out.

Comment: Certainly if a point is trivial, it wouldn't hurt to at least sketch an argument.

Comment: I think anybody who has graded undergraduate analysis assignments has said that at least once.

Comment: Definitely those "easy to see"s, "clearly"s, etc. are good things for referees to zero in on when evaluating a paper. So often those are the critical weak points of a paper.

Comment: Found in the book "Julia, Fatou, Montel : le grand prix" by Michèle Audin (note 21 p.113) : "il y a un résumé de démonstration [] contenant un trou, signalé par un « on démontre aisément que » "

Answer (score 22):

If someone said "of course the equation is well-posed because it is elliptic, etc" it would teach the reader that the statement is not only true, but that there is a well known train of thought for proving the result.

In this sense there is no claim that the proof is short or contains only simple steps, but it does say that that among a certain class of people familiar with the area that it is in fact a well-walked path.

I briefly consulted a dictionary and found these two definitions for "of course"
1. "certainly; definitely"
2. "in the usual or natural order of things"

I am suggesting that "of course" is useful in the second instance as a pedagogical indicator.

I am not claiming that this is always the usage employed in mathematical writing but it is a good one if used in the right circumstances.

Answer (score 16):

Like Konrad Swanepoel, I have found many mistakes, especially in my own work, around "Of course" or comparable expressions, and the saying from one of my early teacher that I often quote is "If it is obvious, then it is easy to prove, so prove it."

That said, I think there are instances where "of course" adds some value to a mathematical text: namely to justify to the reader why you are not taking a seemingly shorter route. Suppose you want to prove a certain assertion, and that in your context, the proof would be easy if some groups were finite, and suppose that in the standard historical paper on the subject that you are generalizing, the groups in question are finite. Then, I think it is helpful to point out at the beginning of your proof or in a remark that "Of course, if the groups were known to be finite, we could use the strategy of...". This "of course", far from drawing attention to how smart the author is, assumes that the *reader* might have anticipated a seemingly shorter proof and explains why this short route was not taken.

Answer (score 15):

Hello,

I agree with some of the comments above: "of course" is useful to point out that some step is trivial (e.g. direct consequence of the definition), as opposed to the rest of non-trivial parts of the proof. Sometimes, "of course" is useful just as an stylistic resource in the writing, to introduce and connect a sentence to the previous one. But it can be very frustrating for the reader if this step is non-trivial, even though the author claims it is.

I was curious about this question and decided to find some examples in the "mathematical literature", as the original poster suggested. I looked through "A Course in Arithmetic", by J-P. Serre (which many consider a very good writer of mathematics) and the expression "of course" appears exactly twice. In both cases, "of course" appears in a parenthetical remark:

1) (p.35) Corollary. - For two nondegenerate quadratic forms over $\mathbb{F}_q$ to be equivalent it is necessary and sufficient that they have same rank and same discriminant. 
(Of course the discriminant is viewed as an element of the quotient group $\mathbb{F}_q^\ast/\mathbb{F}_q^{\ast 2}$.)

2) (p.73) Let $A$ be a subset of $P$ [$P$ is the set of prime numbers]. One says that $A$ has for density a real number $k$ when the ratio 
$$ \left(\sum_{p\in A}\frac{1}{p^s} \right)/ \left(\log \frac{1}{s-1}\right)$$
tends to $k$ when $s\to 1$. (Of course, one then has $0 \leq k \leq 1$.)

In example (1), the way the corollary is stated, a remark is needed - but (i) it is clear from the context that this is what the author means, and (ii) it is typical in this context to consider discriminants only up to squares. Here I see this "of course" as a reminder of (ii).

Example (2) is trickier, as it is not immediately obvious that the limit of the expression as $s\to 1$ is between $0$ and $1$. But I do not interpret this "of course" as a "clearly" in this case, but rather a sort-of "do not worry, if you go back and check Cor 2 in p. 70, you can convince yourself that $0\leq k \leq 1$, and it makes sense to call this number a density".

Álvaro

PS: In "A Course in Arithmetic", the word "clearly" appears many times, while "obviously" was never used in the entire book.

Comment: Serge Lang, also often considered a good writer, uses words like "obvious," "trivial," and "of course" extremely profusely.

Comment: I checked and the expression "of course" appears 61 times in Serge Lang's "Algebra" (2002, Springer, 914 pages). 

Comment: Serge Lang, also often considered a good writer [citation needed]

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there would be an index of "good writers".

Comment: I know, I should return to Axler bashing...

Comment: But never mind that, I want to comment on the answer.  I've been kicking around the idea that, ideally, one should *never* use words like "clearly" in formal (maybe a better word is "careful") mathematical writing.  If something isn't clear, say *something* about why it's true.  If it is clear, then have the confidence to say nothing.

Comment: In practice, for this to work as a reader you have to have extreme trust in the author, both as a mathematician and as a writer.  I find Alvaro's answer interesting because I think of Serre as exactly the sort of person who can get away without writing "clearly".  Knowing that he does it from time to time, the ideal seems too idealistic.

Comment: I generally agree with you about "clearly" (although no doubt I have used that word many a time). Best to be damned certain if one has the temerity to casually toss off that word! :-)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Yes, Serre as one of the most careful writers out there can be "excused", I think, if and when he writes "clearly". (Heh, what am I saying? Serre always writes clearly! I meant, when he writes "obviously" or "of course"!) :-)

Comment: I also wanted to say that even though "no clearly's ever" is clearly an unattainable ideal, I've tried it out recently and noticed that the attempt to at least minimize the use of such words has distinctly improved my writing.  In order to remove the "clearly" I have to think through what it is I'm leaving unsaid; in the process I usually find that my own thoughts about the material become more precise and thorough.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Yep! Another thing I find is that it's a nice gesture to my future (and increasingly forgetful or less sharp) self if I record just a bit more of what I was thinking at the time; I will thank myself later. (I also think I said somewhere in this thread that those "clearly"s are a rich source of weak points in a paper that one is refereeing!) :-)

Comment: (I deleted my comments about Lang.  They don't seem sufficiently relevant to Alvaro's nice answer.)

Comment: (Oh, dang, Pete! I was actually enjoying this! But I guess I'll delete mine too now.)

Comment: @Todd: Feel free to contact me privately.

Comment: I'm not convinced that one can conclude much about how "of course" is used in great English math writing from how "bien sûr" is used in great French math writing.

Answer (score 14):

Please allow me to quote André Weil twice. First, from page 27 of *[The Apprenticeship of a Mathematician](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=73REHmJ9JNUC&dq=The+Apprenticeship+of+a+Mathematician&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=1zaHS4HwIcygkQWa7oVo&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false)*, concerning his first form teacher, Monsieur Collin:

'There was a strong temptation to take short-cuts, saying "it is obvious that..."; Monsieur Collin taught me never to use this word. "If it were obvious," he said, "you would not feel the need to say so; if you say so, that means it is not obvious." He is the one who taught me how to write up mathematics.'

The second quote, from page 19 of *Elliptic Functions According to Eisenstein and Kronecker*:

"Combining the above formulas, we get for all $n\geq 1$, the following series for $E_n(x)$:
$$E_n(x) = u^{-n} \sum_{v=-N}^{+N}\epsilon_n(\zeta + v\tau)+\frac{(2\pi/iu)^n}{(n-1)!}\sum_{v=N+1}^{+\infty}\sum_{d=1}^{+\infty}d^{n-1}q^{vd}[z^d+(-1)^nz^{-d}]$$
where the double series is easily seen to be absolutely convergent provided $N$ has been taken such that $|q^{N+1}z|<1$ and $|q^{N+1}z^{-1}|<1$."

I will refrain from the obligatory *of course* joke and leave the moral of the story as an exercise instead.

Comment: Doing this kind of exercise on Google books is easy and fun to do.
I find that Weil uses the word "obvious" (usually as a short-cut)
10 times in the 92 pages of *Elliptic Functions According to Eisenstein and Kronecker.*

Comment: @John Well,as Weil's mathematical grandson,allow me to defend the great Frenchman by stating that 10 times in 92 pages still has measure 0 by the "lousy teaching" measure function I propose in my post at this thread-which isn't bad at all.

Comment: I don't think you can claim to be anyone's grandson without a PhD...

Answer (score 9):

"of course", "clearly", "obviously", and other like interjections are a form of higher-order punctuation. While strictly speaking they're eliminable, good authors use them as rhythmic elements, cognitive breaths to delimit chunks of an argument. Yes they are "noise words" and phrases, but they are the ones we all know and love (in English) so probably it's best not to press this point too hard. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think I read in Jacobson's BAII (now available from Dover BTW), "Of course, every irreducible module is completely reducible." A sentence that has a problem if only read in English (versus math). Often, "of course," "obviously," and "it is easy to see that" are used solely for the purpose of not starting a sentence with a symbol, or keeping two symbols from being juxtaposed. And sometimes it is important to say something is obvious or a matter of course.

It is good to use the phrases frugally. And it is good to beware when an author uses them. Of course it is obvious that these turns of phrase are useful.

Comment: I don't get it -- it is true that every irreducible module is completely reducible and this immediate from the definition.  What's the problem?  

Comment: @Pete Read it in English as he suggests. "Not reducible at all implies very reducible" seems like nonsense. Obviously, that's not a good translation of the technical meaning, but imagine that you flip the book open to that statement first.

Comment: But statements like that can be true in ordinary English.  To wit: inflammable objects are often completely flammable.

Comment: It's still a possible source of confusion worth a remark. Btw, "flammable" is a corruption of "inflammable." Clearer examples include that we park on driveways and drive on parkways, and that many words are their own opposites, like the verbs "table," "cleave," and "sanction." 

Comment: I read the "of course" in that sentence to be something to counter what was said previously: "(Some statement about irreducible modules); of course [i.e. however,], every irreducible module is completely reducible.

Comment: It might have been more helpful to say "By definition, every irreducible module is completely reducible."

Comment: I tend not to like "By definition..." because *everything* is follows from the definitions...

Comment: OK, I get it now: thanks for the explanation.  As a sentence in a math book though I find it completely unobjectionable.  (Certainly compared to the title: *Basic Algebra II*!)  Anyway, the English word "irreducible" is not much used out of mathematics (possible exception: the recently popular phrase "irreducible complexity"): c.f. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irreducible, where already the first definition alludes to mathematical ideas.

Comment: @Mariano: In some cases, "by definition" serves as a useful substitute for "obviously."  It tells the reader that what follows is easy to see *and* not to waste time trying to infer it from the technical lemmas he's just read --- simply go back to the definition.  It's surprisingly easy to get so engrossed in technical lemmas that one doesn't think to look back at the definition until one is reminded to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Although this is my own experience, it might give an answer to your first question "if something is obvious, then it is obvious that it is obvious (so why include it at all?)." There are times when I will write, "clearly," or "of course," when I feel leaving them out might insult the reader's intelligence. If we imagine your example

> If d divides a and d divides b, then *of course* d also divides a+b,

(probably without the italics) in an advanced context, that is, as a prelude to invoking an important theorem or stating something not so obvious that depends on that simple fact, then I might look at it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago, a professor of mine in a graduate algebra course wrote down a totally impenetrable statement and then added:

"Of course, it's obvious.  It may not be *clear* that it's obvious...but it's obvious."

The words "it's obvious", etc., should be discarded just as the words "We have..." should be discarded.  Also, the words "Consider the following function...."  As Estermann comented..."I do not know what that means."